# How to schedule multiple timings in single Airflow DAG

Tags: python, cron, airflow, etl

I understand that Airflow DAG runs has presets like @hourly, @daily, etc. However, I have interesting use case that I would like to perform **multiple tasks in a single DAG with different schedules**.

For example,

- Task 1 - Every first of the month
- Task 2 - Every second of the month
  at 12pm

..
And so on. Is this possible? These are very simple tasks (such as an API call) with no need to process results so I would like to avoid creating multiple DAGs for each of these tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by using a PythonOperator and the [`croniter`](https://pypi.org/project/croniter/) package.

The DAG could run i.e. @daily and then the PythonOperator calls a functions that checks first if a certain task-specific cron expression matches the execution_date and then executes the code.